# Invalid operation: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type numeric;

Tags: mysql, sql

Invalid operation: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type numeric;

```
select count(asin), recall_case_id 
  from hs3c_prod_stage.d_arnold_activity_batch_asin 
 where region_id='1' 
   AND batch_create_date>'2020-01-01' 
   AND recall_case_id in () 
 group by recall_case_id
   AND ASIN not IN (select asin 
                      from booker.d_unified_cust_shipment_items 
                     where marketplace_id in (1,7))
```

I am getting the following error while executing the code above

> "argument of AND must be type boolean, not type numeric;"

Comment: Hi Sharath, welcome. Could you please detail what datatypes your selected dimensions are? Like, is d_arnold_activity_batch_asin a varchar?

Comment: Don't you have errors when you execute this. `recall_case_id in ()` should result in syntax errors. Also the last AND clause after the group by does not make sense.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: That condition should be part of the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below - `group by` clause will be after `where clause`

```
select count(asin), recall_case_id 
from hs3c_prod_stage.d_arnold_activity_batch_asin 
 where region_id='1' AND batch_create_date>'2020-01-01'
    AND ASIN not IN (select asin 
           from booker.d_unified_cust_shipment_items where marketplace_id in (1,7))
group by recall_case_id
```